# How do you turn on your own faction?

Tags: fallout-4

I finished Fallout 4 with the Brotherhood ending. Is there any way I can betray them? because if you attack the leaders they don't die...

Is there a way to betray the Minutemen as well?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to betray the Minutemen - they're the faction that is available in the instance you betray all of the other factions or side with the Institute but then anger them before completing the story.

If you're finding that it's not possible to kill the leaders of the Brotherhood after completing the game, it's likely that there isn't a way to turn on your faction after completing the game with them.